# Webpack - Inconsistent contenthash between DevServer and build

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, server-side-rendering

I have a script that launches `WebpackDevServer` & `Puppeteer` to create SSR files (HTML) for my site, and at the same time generate the assets (JS, CSS, etc).

However, for some reason, the generated HTML files point to files with a *contenthash* that is different than the actual assets *contenthash*, causing the site to crash.

For example, in the HTML it's looking for:

```html
<script src="/runtime.c38074e6351612e357ee.js"></script>
```

But the actual file receives the name:

```
runtime.4f1783b6674757f40b7c.js
```

Here's a simplified version of my WebPack config:

```js
{
    entry: '/index.js',
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: 'build/',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
    },
    devServer: {
        writeToDisk: true,
        contentBase: 'src/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
    },
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason for the mismatch was some absolute paths generated by some of the plugins/loaders.

Since `webpack-dev-server` serves the files from a location that is different from the build folder, the absolute paths were different, and therefore the `[contenthash]` was different.

This issue was raised to the Webpack team, and to some of the plugin/loader developers, and they fixed it by using relative paths.

Upgrading to the latest webpack/plugins/loaders versions fixed the issue.